# How to put a tikzpicture with caption and a matrix with label next to each other?

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage

I have two things I want to put side by side:

A matrix given by

```
\begin{align} \label{example}
    X = \quad
    \begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
    A & B & C & D \\
    \begin{block}{(cccc)c}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & B \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & C \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & D, \\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{align}
```

and a tikzpicture with a caption that I so far implemented with a figure environment

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,every node/.style={circle,draw},line width=1pt, node distance=1.6cm]
        \node (1)  {A};
        \node (2) [below right of=1] {B};
        \foreach \from/\to in {1/2}
        \node (3) [below left of=1] {C};
        \foreach \from/\to in {2/3,1/3}
        \draw (\from) -- (\to);   
        \node (4) [below left of=2] {D}; 
        \foreach \from/\to in {1/4,2/4,3/4}
        \draw (\from) -- (\to);   
        \path[every node/.style={font=\small}];
    \end{tikzpicture} \caption{Some figure}\label{example2}
\end{figure}
```

I want to now put them side by side but I cannot put the figure in a minipage and also I did not manage to just put the tikzpicture in a minipage - what would be a smart way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Thanks for including some code; but a minimal working example would greatly reduce the amount of work necessary to help you.

Comment: figure and align both use the entire width, but you can't put a figure inside a minipage.  You can however use `\captionof{figure}` (caption package) or just set `\expandafter\def\csname @captype\endcsname{figure}` (inside the minipage) and use `\caption`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! You can use `wrapfig`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[6]{r}[10pt]{4cm}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,every node/.style={circle,draw},line width=1pt, node distance=1.6cm]
        \node (1)  {A};
        \node (2) [below right of=1] {B};
        \foreach \from/\to in {1/2}
        \node (3) [below left of=1] {C};
        \foreach \from/\to in {2/3,1/3}
        \draw (\from) -- (\to);   
        \node (4) [below left of=2] {D}; 
        \foreach \from/\to in {1/4,2/4,3/4}
        \draw (\from) -- (\to);   
        \path[every node/.style={font=\small}];
    \end{tikzpicture} \caption{Some figure}\label{example2}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{align} \label{example}
    X = \quad
    \begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
    A & B & C & D \\
    \begin{block}{(cccc)c}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & B \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & C \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & D, \\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first optional argument, `[6]`, indicates the number of lines that are to be skipped. The "best" value will depend on details like document geometry, font size and so on. Here is the reason why I picked `6`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[6]{r}[10pt]{4cm}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,every node/.style={circle,draw},line width=1pt, node distance=1.6cm]
        \node (1)  {A};
        \node (2) [below right of=1] {B};
        \foreach \from/\to in {1/2}
        \node (3) [below left of=1] {C};
        \foreach \from/\to in {2/3,1/3}
        \draw (\from) -- (\to);   
        \node (4) [below left of=2] {D}; 
        \foreach \from/\to in {1/4,2/4,3/4}
        \draw (\from) -- (\to);   
        \path[every node/.style={font=\small}];
    \end{tikzpicture} \caption{Some figure}\label{example2}
\end{wrapfigure}
Consider the array
\begin{align} \label{example}
    X = \quad
    \begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
    A & B & C & D \\
    \begin{block}{(cccc)c}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & B \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & C \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & D, \\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{align}
The structure of the array is illustrated in Figure~\ref{example2}. 

Some more text \dots some more text \dots some more text \dots some more text
\dots some more text \dots some more text \dots some more text \dots some more
text \dots some more text \dots some more text \dots some more text \dots some
more text \dots some more text \dots some more text \dots some more text
\end{document}
```

[image]

This looks reasonably good in a standard article, but may have to be changed in other documents.

Comment: Looks awesome, I'll try immediately; Thank you very much